# Run FSX (Flight Simulator) on remote desktop

Tags: simulations, microsoft

Obviously I cannot run FSX in a remote desktop session. When I try to start it appears the message: `Flight Simulator cannot run during a Remote Desktop session and will now quit`

Especially for development (coding on a second machine) a RDP session would be handy. Any workarounds for this?

Comment: This sounds like a technical support question for a specific game, which is off-topic here, rather than something related to game development in general. Could you perhaps expand on your problem and what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, I was not aware of this. Somehow this question is difficult to place in any of the stack* locations. If you close it as off topic, it is OK for me. Thought this is the right place here, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using VNC now in order to avoid the issue. While VNC 4.x was not suitable (too slow), VNC 5.x is acceptable for my particular use case.